# How to show difference between original text and edited text?

Tags: php

I have to show difference between two sentence or paragraph. It can be any thing.

Same like in this site original question and edited question.

for example **I love apple** original sentence. and edited sentence is **I do not love banana**, I need is: **do not** and **banana** here. different from original.

How can I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here nice Lib you can use it

**finediff.php**
http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/finediff-code.php

**your-file.php**

```
include 'finediff.php';
$opcodes = FineDiff::getDiffOpcodes($original, $edited);
```

Comment: If someone would like to vote it as negative, could you post a comment so I can learn from my mistakes please

Comment: Hard to say who gave negative vote - but I suppose that author of question. It is problem of some people that if suggested solution is not what he waited, then downvote follows.

Comment: I would not give you downvote (even upvote), but this your way lacks of any introduction, description. Rewrite your post and then it is possible you may get some upvotes or even accepting as the best.

Comment: sorry for late reply. i could not test it due to my own problems.Not  exactly what i want but its ok to use it.Thanks

Comment: The result between
$original='i love apple';
$edited='i love banana banana apple';
is c7i14:banana banana c5
can i get only difference text "banana banana" or character count.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is called the [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), which is a dynamic algorithm that's typically the basis of comparison utilities like a diff utility (also like those you see in svn or git, for example).

Luckily PHP has a massive [PECL](http://pecl.php.net) repository with an [xdiff extension](http://pecl.php.net/xdiff) with just such functions already available for you, such as [`xdiff_string_diff`](http://php.net/xdiff-string-diff)